# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, illegalstateexception, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a webview with one URL, whenever it redirects within the webview, I load the same composable again with a new URL with a new title, as the redirection happens so fast it is happening before the actual composable composes entirely, so it crashes saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
I am currently using ram costa's compose destination library

```kotlin
navigator.value?.navigate(direction = MenuViewDestination,onlyIfResumed = true)
```

, I have used compose provided navigation as well before, I was facing the same problem in both cases, if I navigate with only resumed true then the page is not navigated itself for some reason, and I can't handle the exception as it is happening internally.
Here i have attached the composable used in menu composable to load URL,

```kotlin
/* Adding custom accompanist WebView*/
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun LoadMenuWebView(mainViewModel: MainViewModel, webViewModel: MenuWebViewModel, url: String?) {
    Timber.i("LoadWebView from menu $url")
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var extraHeaders: Map<String, String?>?
    webViewModel.menuWebViewState.value = url?.let {
        rememberWebViewState(
            it
        )
    }
    mainViewModel.currentWebViewClient.value = remember {
        getWebViewClient(
            context,
            mainViewModel.backEnabled,
            mainViewModel.progressVisible,
            mainViewModel.cookieManager,
            mainViewModel
        )
    }
    val state by remember { webViewModel.menuWebViewState }
    val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
    // A custom WebChromeClient can be provided via subclassing
    if (state != null) {
        ObMenuWebView(
            state = state!!,
            captureBackPresses = false,
            onCreated = { webview ->
                webview.settings.apply {
                    javaScriptEnabled = true
                    builtInZoomControls = false
                    displayZoomControls = false
                    loadWithOverviewMode = true
                    cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
                    javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
                    mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                    useWideViewPort = true
                    domStorageEnabled = true
                    // Allow open _blank pages in browser
                    setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
                }
                webview.addJavascriptClient(mainViewModel, context)
              
            },
            navigator = navigator,
            client = remember {
                mainViewModel.currentWebViewClient.value
            },
            chromeClient = remember {
                ExternalPagesClient(context, mainViewModel._showExternalLinkDialog)
            },
            webViewModel = webViewModel
        )
    }

}
```

important thing to note here is i have modified the accompanist webview a bit and using ViewModel to store the instance of the existing webview because accompanist webview recomposes everytime i navigate between composable within app which leads to reloads of webview, so did that workaround for now, i know storing view instances in ViewModel might cause memory leaks but i had no other way,

```kotlin
/**
 * A wrapper around the Android View WebView to provide a basic WebView composable.
 *
 * If you require more customisation you are most likely better rolling your own and using this
 * wrapper as an example.
 *
 * @param state The webview state holder where the Uri to load is defined.
 * @param captureBackPresses Set to true to have this Composable capture back presses and navigate
 * the WebView back.
 * @param navigator An optional navigator object that can be used to control the WebView's
 * navigation from outside the composable.
 * @param onCreated Called when the WebView is first created, this can be used to set additional
 * settings on the WebView. WebChromeClient and WebViewClient should not be set here as they will be
 * subsequently overwritten after this lambda is called.
 * @param client Provides access to WebViewClient via subclassing
 * @param chromeClient Provides access to WebChromeClient via subclassing
 * @sample com.google.accompanist.sample.webview.BasicWebViewSample
 */
@Composable
fun ObMenuWebView(
    state: com.ob_core_framework.base.WebViewState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    captureBackPresses: Boolean = true,
    navigator: WebViewNavigator = rememberWebViewNavigator(),
    onCreated: (WebView) -> Unit = {},
    client: com.ob_core_framework.base.AccompanistWebViewClient = remember { com.ob_core_framework.base.AccompanistWebViewClient() },
    chromeClient: com.ob_core_framework.base.AccompanistWebChromeClient = remember { com.ob_core_framework.base.AccompanistWebChromeClient() },
    webViewModel: MenuWebViewModel
) {

    var existingWebView by remember { webViewModel.existingWebView }


    BackHandler(captureBackPresses && navigator.canGoBack) {
        existingWebView?.goBack()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(existingWebView, navigator) {
        with(navigator) { existingWebView?.handleNavigationEvents() }
    }

    // Set the state of the client and chrome client
    // This is done internally to ensure they always are the same instance as the
    // parent Web composable
    client.stateLocal = state
    client.navigatorLocal = navigator
    chromeClient.stateLocal = state

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            existingWebView ?: WebView(context).apply {
                onCreated(this)

                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )

                webChromeClient = chromeClient
                webViewClient = client
            }.also {
                existingWebView = it
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) { view ->
        when (val content = state.content) {
            is WebContent.Url -> {
                val url = content.url

                if (url.isNotEmpty() && url != view.url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url, content.additionalHttpHeaders.toMutableMap())
                }
            }
            is WebContent.Data -> {
                view.loadDataWithBaseURL(content.baseUrl, content.data, null, "utf-8", null)
            }
        }

        navigator.canGoBack = view.canGoBack()
        navigator.canGoForward = view.canGoForward()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show the portion of the code where you compose the WebView

Comment: @Rafsanjani added the composable, please let me know if you can help in anyway

Comment: Where do you get `ObMenuWebView` from? I'm assumming this composable is using an AndroidView and initializing it in the factory using a regular WebView. That's the portion of the code i'm interested in seeing

Comment: @Rafsanjani I have added that composable too, as I already mentioned it is a slightly modified accompanist library's webview composable, only thing different here is i am using the webview from ViewModel which is 
var existingWebView by remember { webViewModel.existingWebView }

Answer (score 7):

An Android View cannot have more than one parents.

In your `AndroidView` lambda, you can check if the view has already been given a parent, which will be true during recompositions because you are remembering your `View`. If it has a parent, you should remove the view from the parent's view hierarchy.

You can modify the factory in `ObMenuWebView` and add the following

```
factory = { context ->
        existingWebView ?: WebView(context).apply {
            onCreated(this)

            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )

            webChromeClient = chromeClient
            webViewClient = client
        }.also {
            if(it.parent != null) (it.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(it) // this line is very crucial
            existingWebView = it
        }
    },
```

Comment: I get the same issue even after adding this, but now the scenario is if the click any link within that webview and trying to navigate to same composable with new hyperlink clicked which needed to be loaded in the webview

Comment: @Rafsanjani I'm facing the same problem but for me, i'm using AndroidView in Lazy Lists and when i do scrolling it throws me the same error for the parent.
I saw that there is onReset method for AndroidView and then i'm trying to also remove the parent but still no success...